# maximum size of a sqlite db per iphone app

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, core-data

Kindly get me the limits of following things in sqlite of iphone

1. No of rows that can be created
2. Maximum size of the database per app.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953052/what-is-the-maximum-sandbox-size-on-ipad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no hard limit, except available Flash storage on the phone.

The number of rows is limited to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (because rowid is 64 bits wide), which is essentially unlimited...

Comment: 2^64? Shouldn't the number be 18446744073709551616?