# Caching data on the iphone. Max size of stored data

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I was discussing the requirements of an app and I am a little lost with a few things.

1)
I will be getting data back from a web server via JSON. The user wants the data cached for a month so that there is no unnecessary data usage. My concern is that the data base on the webserver is about 300mb in size. If the user is very active this could mean there could be a lot of data cached on the phone. Is there a limit to the amount of storage you can use? Would 50mb of cached data be realistic to store?

2)
If i was to store all this data, what would be the best way to handle it? Since i would need to be able to search and manage the data from the device. Is this a realistic request from the client, or is the iphone really not suited to this kind of operation. Would it be best to not cache the data at all and just pull it down with JSON as required.

Many Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) framework with SQLite for storage.

According to the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080084/maximum-size-of-a-sqlite-db-per-iphone-app), there is no specific limit to how much data you can store other than the device's flash storage size.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a limit to the amount of storage you can use? Would 50mb of cached data be realistic to store?

No, there is no limit except the capacity of the iPhone's flash memory. 50 MB is not that much IMO, considering there are apps that are hundreds of megabytes large.