# iPhone Documents directory maximum size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, directory, documents

I'm just wondering due to new personal project which is the limit (in MB  or GB) of documents directory of my app. I just wanna save a lot of photos, so, has documents directory a limit for archiving downloaded photos? Will saving 300MB of photos produce slow downs on 3G?
If there is no limit, I think that limit shoud be the 8 16 32 GB of the iPhone, are there any method to know the free space?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the maximum sandbox size on iPad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953052/what-is-the-maximum-sandbox-size-on-ipad)

Comment: Search before posting. This is easily found on SO.

Answer (score -1):

According to a discussions.apple.com: There is a limit of 2 GB.

https://discussions.apple.com/message/7599983?messageID=7599983#7599983?messageID=7599983

Files in the document directory stay there permanently until the app is removed.

Comment: The thread you're referencing does not pertain to documents directory size.