# iPad local data storage limit

Tags: ipad

Can anyone tell me what is the maximum size that can be download from the web
and can be stored locally.

Comment: Check   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921048/limit-of-localstorage-on-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is 5 MB.
See also [this S.O. post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921048/limit-of-localstorage-on-iphone).

You could also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772908/max-size-ipad-iphone-offline-application-cache) if you are interested in going beyond that limit.

EDIT: after your comment I see you are not referring to [local web storage](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Name-ValueStorage/Name-ValueStorage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007256-CH6-SW1). Local web storage is a new possibility offered by HTML5 to store key-value pairs. This has got the limitation I was mentioning.

As to your case, I don't think that there is some restrictive limit on the amount of data you can download and store locally (in your Documents directory) in order to access it later. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214644/iphone-documents-directory-maximun-size), where answers range from a minimum of 2GB of flash space to no limit at all. So you can be safe.

If you are referring to the limit in the total amount of data you can download over 3G connections (also called over-the-air download), [this is 20MB](http://www.tuaw.com/2010/02/18/apple-may-have-upped-its-over-the-air-download-limits-for-app-st/). You are only allowed to download a larger file when using Wi-Fi.

Comment: I had downloaded one zip file of 31 MB and stored it locally then unzipped it. it is html web site content so i had load that into webview. I want to know i am restricted to 50 MB or 100 MB?

Comment: Thanks Sergio. i got my answer. there is no restriction/limit for download.