# Storage quota for app in iPhone / iPad

Tags: iphone, file, ipad, system, storage

I am just wondering what's the storage size for an iPad/iPhone app to use?

For memory, it is sure that every app can only use 100MB-like memory.

How about the storage? I mean the file system in iPad/iPhone app?

Use as much as I want until the file system is full? or something like that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the maximum sandbox size on iPad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953052/what-is-the-maximum-sandbox-size-on-ipad)

Answer (score 1):

Use as much as you want until the file system is full, though that will be a terrible idea and users will just remove the app. So try to use as small as you can.

Answer (score 0):

> Use as much as I want until the file system is full?

Yes.