# What is the maximum level of storage for app data in allowed for ios Devices?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios-4.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the maximum sandbox size on iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953052/what-is-the-maximum-sandbox-size-on-ipad)

Hii to all,

we have a assignment for ios app which contains client files which comes around 1 GB , so user opens the app , upon authentication - it will download files from remote server & it should be stored to iphone's internal storage , when any of the files get update that files needs to be downloaded & stored as well,

My question is is that possible ti download such high memory of data remotely?

also is ios devices allows to store app related data around 1 GB content in its internal storage?

Thank you,

Comment: @charlie - Thanks charlie - But is explains only the size of an app - that's not my question.

Comment: When I google around to find some info for my answer, if all of that info comes from other stackoverflow questions, it might be a dupe! :)

Comment: OK, how about this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953052/what-is-the-maximum-sandbox-size-on-ipad Did you actually try to find the answer before asking?

Comment: @charlie : you are the man , thanks it seems its pretty close to wat i m expecting>

Answer (score 0):

You can save them, but downloading the whole file over the network might not be a good idea. You should package it up with your download instead of trying to download it remotely.

For updating it, you could use `ASIHTTPRequest` with the `shouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground` parameter set to `YES`, so it doesn't stop downloading once the user leaves your application.

But 1GB? What sort of content is it? Maybe we can figure out a way to split it into multiple network calls or something?

Comment: Thanks & App concept is like showcase its various product portfolis which comes with any kind of content like pdf , doc, video,audio etc

Comment: Is it practical to push out an update every time the video content changes instead of trying to download it automatically? That might be much simpler ..

Comment: Yes But Video Content changes for every month & other content will vary for every 2 -3 days.

Comment: Hmm.. The only other thing I can think of to avoid this is to host the video online and stream it instead of downloading the whole video file. That's all I can think of for now, if that doesn't work for you, maybe someone else can come up with a better answer ..