# Disk space for downloaded files in ios app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, filesystems, app-store-connect

My app downloads files. How much space I can use for downloaded files? App size is 3-4 mbytes. I save files to documents folder.

Comment: Potential duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953052/what-is-the-maximum-sandbox-size-on-ipad

Comment: AFAIK there is no quota, you're just limited by free space ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no capacity limit except the available storage (except for the fact that the app may see a bit less storage then what is actually available on the device - some may be saved for the OS).

To get the free storage available on the device (as your app is concerned):

```
NSString* docsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:docsDir error:NULL];
unsigned long long freeSpaceInBytes = [[fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize] unsignedLongLongValue];
NSLog(@"Memory Capacity of %llu MiB.", ((freeSpaceInBytes/1024ll)/1024ll));
```