# Is there any limitation on storage of an app on iPad?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, storage

I am developing an iPad app for some clients.
This app is like a magazine that have so many different documents and videos to use. The users wants to access all their documents, videos, and other files even when offline.

I wonder if it is possible to download 3500 different files and store them locally in IPAD and make them accessible while offline.

Is there any storage limitation for each app?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the maximum sandbox size on iPad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953052/what-is-the-maximum-sandbox-size-on-ipad)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a recent limitation you should be aware of for apps that require large storage & offline use:

http://www.marco.org/2011/10/13/ios5-caches-cleaning

Comment: Thanks! I have another question. The usage of this app is internal usage and won't be submitted to iTunes, would it be the same scenario again?

Comment: Yes, any content that is intended to be downloaded (and therefore re-downloaded at any time) is supposed to go in the Caches folder, which can (and will) be cleaned up outside of your control.  If you put it in Documents it can be backed up by iCloud and you risk getting pulled from the app store.

Comment: If your app is distributed outside the app store, then you're probably ok.  I have an internal app that has 3.5gb of data in the documents directory and it works just fine (just takes forever to distribute).

Comment: Looks like this has been addressed in 5.0.1: http://www.macrumors.com/2011/11/02/apple-posts-ios-5-0-1-beta-for-developers/

Comment: Done! This question is completely answered!