# Maximum size of document directory in Iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to store images and videos in document directory,So i want to know that maximum how much data i can store in document directory that it will not give me memory warning.

Can anyone tell me maximum data storage possible for document directory in Iphone?

Comment: You get memory warnings about RAM, not about disk space.  Can you explain your question better?

Comment: possible duplicate of What is the maximum sandbox size on iPad (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953052/what-is-the-maximum-sandbox-size-on-ipad)?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The links bellow may be of some help:

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/4083-limit-restrictions-filesize-filecount-app-folder.html

https://discussions.apple.com/message/7599983?messageID=7599983#7599983?messageID=7599983

Comment: you have given two links which you probably found with google. The first one seems to answer the question because of the title but both only answer the maximum size of the application but not of the documents folder.

Answer (score 4):

> I think there is no limit to the size of your sandbox other than the
>   remaining capacity of the device itself.

Answer (score -1):

According to apple..

> To manage program memory, iPhone OS uses essentially the same virtual
>   memory system found in Mac OS X. In iPhone OS, each program still has
>   its own virtual address space, but (unlike Mac OS X) its usable
>   virtual memory is constrained by the amount of physical memory
>   available. This is because iPhone OS does not write volatile pages to
>   disk when memory gets full. Instead, the virtual memory system frees
>   up volatile memory, as needed, to make sure the running application
>   has the space it needs. It does this by removing memory pages that are
>   not being used and that contain read-only contents, such as code
>   pages. Such pages can always be loaded back into memory later if they
>   are needed again.
>
> If memory continues to be constrained, the system may also send
>   notifications to the running applications, asking them to free up
>   additional memory. All applications should respond to this
>   notification and do their part to help relieve the memory pressure.
>   For information on how to handle such notifications in your
>   application, see “Observing Low-Memory Warnings.”

so there is no size limit as such...

Comment: you have an extract talking about RAM instead of directory size.