# How to discard graphics assets from device to minimise flash storage requirements?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm thinking about the large size of new iPad graphics here. Anyone with an original iPad or iPad 2 that downloads a retina-updated app will also be getting @2x image resources. For graphically intensive apps this will be a huge burden. To a lesser extent it is a problem with iPhone 3GS apps downloading apps where just about all of them now have retina display graphics included too. These older devices will never use the @2x image resources so they do nothing but consume storage.

On AskDifferent [a question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/46527/3117) was posted this morning that shows some scary figures for retina-updated apps. I haven't verified them but apps are getting drastically bigger. iMovie is the worst example, almost 6x the size!

The ultimate solution is vector graphics but in some cases it will be impractical and many developers updating existing apps will be wanting to just add new images and do the minimum to get an update out quickly.

How could this be done? The application documents directory is where an app can easily remove and discard files, but I believe there are limitations on the amount of data an app may install in documents? And in any other location the app can't remove files?

If this could be done then post-install the app would just delete the unused resources, keeping the specific resources it requires for the device it is on.

One problem I can see with this is that the `Transfer Purchases from` feature of iTunes would no longer be retrieving an app that is useful for other kinds of devices. An app using this feature might need to retain baseline graphics for both iPhone and iPad, and be capable of updating itself with retina versions (by download) if installed to another device.

Answer (score 0):

The differences are probably not so huge in many apps. It is always up to the developer to decide what resolution they will ship with an app.

It is 'possible' to muck about in the bundle, adding/removing things, but it isn't a good idea. There are no limits on the size of the documents dir (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953052/what-is-the-maximum-sandbox-size-on-ipad), but that would be a huge pain. Having everything in the bundle makes development convenient.

One solution would be to push separate iPad/iPhone versions. The iPad version would be a bit larger than the iPhone, but if users want shiny, they'll have to deal.