# itunes filesharing of app stucks in between

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, itunes, file-sharing

Recently I have developed iPad app with filesharing enabled. It is an app to display photos with other options.

Photos will be transferred from windows xp and it range between 7000 to 10000 and total size may be up till 3-4 gb. 
I am just trying to implement it and when transfer in progress hardly 600-700 files, itunes get stuck in between with unknown error. It gets stuck randomly in between and crashes.

I have tried with installing itunes on another computer and copy images there but same result. Stucks somewhere in between with unknown error and itunes shutdowns.

I am wondering whats going on here. Does itunes has limit in filesharing for app? Do i have to change something in my app? App has limit in size it can use? Ipad is newly brought and has 60 gb of memory.

Please provide any guidance or possible cause of crash.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The app size is max 2GB, [but there is no limit to the size of the sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2953427/251513).

Comment: ok thanks, so what could be other cause of itunes crash while transferring files? I have tried in 2 pcs so definitely something wrong is going on but can't guess what..

Comment: Sorry, is not easy to understand what could be the problem. Have you tried with a Mac?

Comment: haven't tried on mac yet. Do you think there is any process running on iPad/iphone when file transfer is in progress? some process on device might cause unexceptional error? I tried by closing the app when file transfer in progress but no effect. Tried to isolate in iphone configuration utility too but no clues..